# $H_q(X) = 0$ if $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, real-numbers

Is it true that if $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then $H_q(X) = 0$ if $q \geq n$. I have this statement (unproved) in my algebraic topology notes and I'd like to know whether this is true just for the sake of having "true math written in my notes". Any reference of the eventual proof, patological(or simple) counterexample that works will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, assuming you mean the singular homology.

**Example** ([Barratt & Milnor 1962](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9.pdf)) The $r$-dimensional analogue of the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)
$$
X_r=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigg\{(x_0,\dots,x_r)\in\mathbb{R}^{r+1}:\bigg(x_0-\frac1n\bigg)^2+x_1^2+\dots+x_r^2=\frac1{n^2}\bigg\}
$$
has nonzero rational singular homology groups in dimension $q\equiv 1\pmod{r-1}$ ($r,q>1$).  In fact, $H_q(X_r;\mathbb{Q})$ is not even countable (equivalently, countably generated).

On the other hand, with another homology theory, it could be true.  For example, a compact $X$ with covering dimension $<q$, the Čech homology group $\check{H}_q(X)=0$ (in particular works for $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{q-1}$), but the
Čech homology theory is also not that well-behaved when you move out to more general spaces.